# NLTK error using php

Tags: php, python, nltk

I am developing a PHP website. I have an extra requirement to make a recommendation system. Python is best in that case. I already developed recommendation system in python and it works well. Now I want to combine python recommendation system with my PHP website. When I call python file from my PHP webpage I am getting beloow error.

```
  Resource u'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle' not found.  Please
  use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>>
  nltk.download()
```

I have all my code in my local wamp server for now.  I am using `PHP 5.6.19` and `WAMP 3.0.4`, `Python 2.7.11`
Can anyone help for this problem ?

Comment: If the file is indeed where it is looking, check permissions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include a [Minimal, Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Another useful link: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. 
I have moved my python code inside of my PHP website root folder. I put. I have changed my trm (python folder) permission with Full Control. I have my php_python.php file inside of trm. So I am calling call.py file from php_python.php file from the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to my problem.
When I was running code from python shell, it was able to locate "nltk_data" folder but It was not able to reach this folder when I was trying to execute same code from PHP.
I have added "nltk_data" path manually as shown below in my Python code once after importing nltk libraries and It has solved my problem.

`import nltk
nltk.data.path.append('c:/users/.../AppData/Roaming/nltk_data/')`

Comment: Good work. Indeed, the nltk looks at a list of standard locations for its data, so moving it or changing users causes problems. Since you were the first to find the solution to the problem, please "accept" your own answer by clicking on the big check mark to its left. It marks your question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

`nltk.download()` should be run from a Python shell which was started with root permissions. On Debian for example, `su`, `(yourrootpassword)` `python` and `nltk.download()`. You should be able to download everything there.

The import for NLTK is NOT enough to use it. You need to download all the corpora and tokenizers to make use of it.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Ares. When I execute my code in python shell it works perfect. The problem is when I call that python file from my php file. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: Can you please edit the code you used in Python and in PHP into your original question?

Comment: I am unable to add whole code but I have uploaded my code on Git. Could you please download it from here : https://github.com/mitulparekh90/temp/tree/master/Collaborative

Comment: Yes I did, Please see `collaborative_er_sem.py` File. I believe If you run `Collaborative.py` file in python shell you will receive output.

Comment: I think the issue is probably in your server permissions. Does the server have access to the nltk_data folder located in the directory you were in when you called `nltk.download()`?